# Django requests : response much slower than function itself

Tags: python, django, performance, python-requests, memcached

My application has performance issues (worsening during busy hours).
I've noticed following strange behaviour :

When I set up the django enviroment:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings.test")
django.setup()
```

and try to run the function itself: views.dataCheckFunction (9277 is entry parameter)

```
for i in range(1,10):
    zac=datetime.now()
    views.dataCheckFunction(9227)
    kon=datetime.now()
    delta=kon-zac
    print(delta)
```

It runs as expected and each run takes from 0.7s to 1s

However when I try to call same function via

```
for i in range(1,10):
    zac=datetime.now()
    res = requests.get(url='https://profiextra-test.generali.sk/api/policy/9227/dataCheckFunction/',
                 headers={'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'})
    kon=datetime.now()
    delta=kon-zac
    print(delta)
```

The duration of each call is very volatile and it can be from 2.3s to 10s

The function makes approx 200 database calls.
To reduce the traffic I use Memcache
Any idea what can be the cause ?

Thanks

Comment: what is dataCheckFunction how is it coded? can you share its code?....requests is doing a real http request no mocking or something like that

Comment: Maybe try caching those url responses or just store those information in DB. Then you do not have to call any API.

Comment: HTTP requests usually take a lot of time. Especially if these are in a `for` loop, and if the view behind it does a lot of work. Usually the idea is to minimize HTTP requests, try to "batch" instructions in a single call, run requests in parallel, and ensure that the view you use itself is efficient. But most of the efficiency problems are indeed not the view itself, but the HTTP traffic behind it.